# Windows console breaks when printing while asking for input in Java

Tags: java, windows, input, console

I'm experimenting with networking by writing a small chat-room program in Java. Because it's a chat-room, the console is constantly asking for input from the user. My problem is that, after printing a message from another person in the server whilst still asking for input, the console stops showing what I type. Input is still collected, however, so the user can still input messages. There's just no visual feedback. I've tried three different methods of input, BufferedReader (which I'm still currently using), a Scanner, and the system console. They all have the same problem, which leads me to believe it's the windows console. My question is, is it possible to avoid this or is it simply a flaw with the Windows console? Here is my code, with input being the BufferedReader:

```
    // This runs until the console is closed
    while(true)
    {
        // If the user has input something, send it to the server
        if(input.ready())
        {
            String message = input.readLine();
            if(!message.equals(""))
            {
                client.sendString(message);
            }
        }

        // If the server has a message for the client, print it
        if(client.input.available() > 0)
        {
            System.out.println(client.getString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: "while", so there should be an iteration somewhere. Can't tell from the code you show, though

Comment: Show more code please

Comment: A console program is a very bad choice for a *live* chat program, because printing a new incoming message while user is typing will break the text being typed.

Comment: I don't think you can reasonably expect Java to implement this for you.  Just echo the characters yourself.

Comment: Show the `getString()` and the server side code that sends the message.

Comment: I've added the loop into the code here, however I don't think more code is necessary. The only important details are how input is retrieved, and how output is printed. I do understand that it's unreasonable to expect this to be "fixed", I was just hoping it could already be worked around.